# How to get all custom field values for specific field for custom post type WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I will try to explain my question as best for the community as I can.

I have a **custom post type** in WordPress named "people" (which is the slug).

Each post type belonging to "people" has an **Advanced Custom Field** associated with it, simply named "number". The field type is a **number**.

Here is what I want to achieve:

I want to get the values for **number** for all the posts, on a **foreach** for example, that carries on for as many posts there are.

I then want to add all of these values up to produce a total.

I know how to handle the calculations in PHP, that's not an issue.

Can you please advice on the best way to collect all the numbers in the custom fields for all posts, and how to store them in order to calculate the total.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you use the CPTs archive? Run a while loop through all the posts and calculate the total inside the loop like `$total += $value;` (inside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I can think of is to get all posts for people post type and then get the field data.

The approach for that will be some thing like:

```
$peoplePosts = get_posts(
                   array(
                       'post_type'      =>  'people',
                       'posts_per_page'  =>  -1
                   ));
$sum = 0;
print_r(peoplePosts);
if (is_array($peoplePosts)) {
    foreach ( $peoplePosts as $peoplePost) {
        $currentVal = get_field('number', $peoplePost->ID);
        $sum = (float) $sum + (float) $currentVal;
    }
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I will point out that there are 2 errors in your example, which broke my page. 1) A missing closing `'` after `posts_per_page`. 2) You didn't close `(is_array` with a `)`. After fixing those however, your code worked perfectly, and you have provided a perfect solution to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @T.Sheen My apologies for the error in the code. To be honest I am half asleep right now but I am glad it worked for you. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get_posts()` (wordpress builtin method) to get all posts from that post type like this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type'        => 'people',
               'posts_per_page'   => -1
             );

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Then you can do a `foreach` loop through all of the posts like this:

```
if(!empty($posts))
{
    $total = 0;

    foreach($posts as $p)
    {
       $total += get_field('number', $p->ID);
    }
}
```